# How can I use Fragment's Spinner events in my main class?

Tags: java, android, spinner, onitemclicklistener

the code below named `Presenteter` is my main class, and I am replacing the `Fragment` according to questions.

```
public class Presenteter extends AppCompatActivity   {
    private final Questions question1Fragment = new Questions();
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.present);

FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out);

         ft.replace(R.id.flPersonalization, question1Fragment);

        ft.commit();
}
```

This is my `Questions` class. It is getting the questions from REST server. All questions are listed in in one `Spinner`. I didn't write them here, in order not to confuse you.

```
public class Questions extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    SearchableSpinner spinner;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question, container, false);
  LinearLayout ln=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.listLayout);
          spinner=(SearchableSpinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
}
```

Finally I want to use `Spinner`'s `onItemSelected()` event in my `Presenter` class.

How can I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this in your `Fragment`:

```
Presenteter p = (Presenteter) getActivity();

// ...

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        p.yourMethod(); // call a method of your Presenteter class
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad your question is answered but there is a better way for doing this.

If you are familiar with Rx stuff, that's one way to do it.

If Rx is not your cup of tea, you can use EventBus which simplifies exactly this kind of communication. 
Link:
[EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

I would suggest going for the latter if you are not sure.

Comment: Thank you so much,I am not so good at android,not even a juniour :),But I like them which you told me.I am sure I will use them rest of my apps. :)

Comment: I'm glad that I helped you. EventBus is really saviour sometimes but as you learn more and more, you will find other ways to solve this situation.